# I want to know the natural expression for contrasting

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I want to elucidate the characteristics of one object, contrasting to another object at the end of the sentence. However, I am not sure whether these expressions natural or not. Please let me know what are the natural sentences in the followings.

Microwave is an energy-efficient tool for heating the material -

1. distinct from dry oven.
2. different from dry oven
3. other than dry oven.
4. contrasting to dry oven.

Or I will terribly appreciate you if you let me know other expressions which could deliver the same meaning in the more fluent form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use this structure here as follows. This is because in such case you will be comparing "*the material*" with the "*dry oven*". There are few ways to fix this:

- The dry oven **is distinct from** the microwave in that the latter is an energy-efficient tool for heating the material.
- **Unlike** the dry oven, the microwave is an energy-efficient tool for heating the material.
- **In contrast to** the dry oven, the microwave is an energy-efficient tool for heating the material.
- The microwave **differs from** the dry oven in that the former is an energy-efficient tool for heating the material.

In respect to your comment:

- A microwave is an energy-efficient tool for heating the material, **whereas** a dry oven isn't.
- The microwave is an energy-efficient tool for heating the material, **unlike** the dry oven.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, isn't there other ways to contrast at the end of the sentence as I intended firstly? Because the content of the characteristic I want to explain is important and comparing is secondary.

Comment: There is in fact

Comment: For example,
"Because of its large particle size, applications of A are much limited" are important content, and I want to compare at the end of this sentence like:
"unlike B."

Comment: "**Because of its large particle size, applications of A are much limited, whereas those of B aren't.**" or "**Because of its large particle size, applications of A are much limited, which isn't the case for B.**"

Comment: @Sungil, None of the other words that you suggested provide the same meaning  as **unlike**  in the sentence in your question.

Comment: @SovereignSun: that should be "isn't the case **for** B".

Comment: @JavaLatte Sorry, yes, you're right.

Comment: @SovereignSun Thank you very much! It is really helpful.

Comment: @JavaLatte Do you mean that all of the sentences I wrote in the question are wrong? Or grammatically acceptable but have different meaning?

Comment: @Sungil, the sentences that you wrote are not clear because you have probably not used enough determiners ""a"* and  **the**: Compare SovereignSun's versions with your own. In addition, none of the clauses that you wanted to add at the end work in that position. See SovereignSun's explanation.**, unlike a dry oven** would work in that position.

Comment: @JavaLatte I fully understand your explanation! Thank you :)